# Как установить прелоадер на сайт на время загрузки страницы?

Tags: css, html5

Пример прелоадера на сайте [codepen](http://codepen.io/jackrugile/pen/JddmaX) сделан на html и css, как его установить на время загрузки страницы. Если просто вставить, то прелоадер работает бесперестано поверх контента.

HTML:
    
        
            
                
            
            
                
            
            
                
            
            
                
            
            
                
            
        
    
CSS:

```
.loader {
    background: #000;
    background: radial-gradient(#222, #000);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.loader-inner {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

.loader-line-wrap {
    animation: 
        spin 2000ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite
    ;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
.loader-line {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: -50ms; }
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: -100ms; }
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: -150ms; }
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: -200ms; }
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: -250ms; }

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(0, 80%, 60%);
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    top: 7px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(60, 80%, 60%);
    height: 76px;
    width: 76px;
    top: 14px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(120, 80%, 60%);
    height: 62px;
    width: 62px;
    top: 21px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(180, 80%, 60%);
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    top: 28px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(240, 80%, 60%);
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    top: 35px;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0%, 15% {
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
/* Preloader */ 
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").delay(100).fadeOut().remove();    

});
```

```css
.loader {
    background: #000;
    background: radial-gradient(#222, #000);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.loader-inner {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

.loader-line-wrap {
    animation: 
  spin 2000ms cubic-bezier(.175, .885, .32, 1.275) infinite
 ;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
.loader-line {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: -50ms; }
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: -100ms; }
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: -150ms; }
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: -200ms; }
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: -250ms; }

.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(1) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(0, 80%, 60%);
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    top: 7px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(2) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(60, 80%, 60%);
    height: 76px;
    width: 76px;
    top: 14px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(3) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(120, 80%, 60%);
    height: 62px;
    width: 62px;
    top: 21px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(4) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(180, 80%, 60%);
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    top: 28px;
}
.loader-line-wrap:nth-child(5) .loader-line {
    border-color: hsl(240, 80%, 60%);
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    top: 35px;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0%, 15% {
  transform: rotate(0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<div class="loader">
 <div class="loader-inner">
  <div class="loader-line-wrap">
   <div class="loader-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="loader-line-wrap">
   <div class="loader-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="loader-line-wrap">
   <div class="loader-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="loader-line-wrap">
   <div class="loader-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="loader-line-wrap">
   <div class="loader-line"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>



 <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/9XHjO5THz_U" alt="">
```

---

**Update**

С задержкой:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  setTimeout(function () { 
    $(".loader").delay(100).fadeOut().remove();   
  }, 2000);  
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, скажите, куда более приемлемо вставлять html код?? (я изначально вставляю в head)

Comment: @Эмиль,`<body> <div class="loader" > ... </div> .... </body>`

Comment: Скажите, а как минимум на 2 секунды показывать, так как прогрузка быстрее совершается и прелоадер даже не заметить??

Comment: @Эмиль, добавила в ответ для задержки можно `setTimeout` использовать